# ElasticBeanstalk to handle script that runs only in 1 instance at the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

```
#!/bin/sh

SQS_QUEUE_URL="url"
AWS_REGION="eu-central-1"
LOCK_KEY="supervisor-lock"
# Unique identifier for the lock

# Attempt to acquire the lock by sending a message to the queue
lock_acquired=$(aws sqs send-message --queue-url "$SQS_QUEUE_URL" --region "$AWS_REGION" --message-body "$LOCK_KEY")
echo "Lock Acquired: $lock_acquired"

sleep 5

message=$(aws sqs receive-message --queue-url "$SQS_QUEUE_URL" --region "$AWS_REGION" --max-number-of-messages 1 --wait-time-seconds 0 --query "Messages[0].ReceiptHandle")

echo $message

if [ -n "$message" ]; then

    if [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "development" ]; then
        echo "Starting Supervisor setup..."
        # handle in case you here it fails
        sudo mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
        sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery
        cp -r /var/app/current/supervisor /etc
        export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
        source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
        #/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/project-supervisord.conf shutdown
        #sleep 5
        /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/project-supervisord.conf
        echo "Starting Supervisor..."

        # Release the lock by deleting the message from the queue
        aws sqs delete-message --queue-url "$SQS_QUEUE_URL" --receipt-handle "$message" --region eu-central-1

        echo "message deleted"
    elif [ "$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" = "production" ]; then
        # Start supervisor only in development environment
        echo "Skipping Supervisor setup in production environment."
    fi

else
    echo "Failed to acquire the lock. Another instance is already setting up Supervisor."
fi
```

So I have an EB env that runs always 2 instances in parallel. When I deploy I want the commands to run only in one instance.
So the idea is to have a message lock mechanism so that the 2 instances somehow have a way to communicate.
I also want this to be resilient to ec2 replacement due to autoscaling kicking in.
So if the instance running the supervisor gets replaced it should run the supervisor again. Always and only in 1 instance at the time.

The result I get from this script atm is that the commands get to run in both instances and I have 2 messages left in the queue.

What I want to get is 0 messages in the queue and supervisor running in 1 instance.

I did manually run those commands and they all work, the delete as well but seems like is not deleting the message, I do get the print message as well.

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run your script using [Container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) with `leader_only` flag set to `true`. This way it will execute only on one instance.

Comment: ok nice, I use eb hooks on post-deploy is there a way to do it with it or better to move the script to container command ?

   00_deploy_hook_permissions:
     command: |
       sudo find .platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
       sudo find /var/app/staging/.platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R

Comment: I'm running this now : ````

Comment: So on deploy it does run the commands only in 1 instance. However if I kill the leader instance the one that gets replaces does not run the command. Seems like does not know it should be a leader if leader fails. Or ?

Comment: I've found out that on replacement it does not know who is the leader or not and it takes little time before a new leader is assign. How to solve my issue then ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now running this :

```
container_commands:
  00_deploy_hook_permissions:
    command: |
      sudo find .platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
      sudo find /var/app/staging/.platform/ -type f -iname "*.sh" -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
  01_run_supervisor_script:
    command: chmod +x script/celery.sh
    leader_only: true
```

so moved the script in script/celery.sh I can see from the logs that the command was executed but looks like it did not.

My modify script for testing :

`````
#!/bin/sh


sudo mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/celery
cp -r /var/app/current/supervisor /etc
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate

/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/project-supervisord.conf

````

Am I missing anything here ?
`````

Comment: problem looks solved running the commands directly and not through a script with leader_only = true. Thank you so much